# Regular expression, reading character by character(java)

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

Sorry for my English. Read file character by character. I need to output a string that meets our expression, in this case `([a-zA-Z0-9]){0,}`. That's how I did it: if a line break occurs, then there is a check on the regular expression. Why does not it work?

UDP code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        int endWord = wordToFind.length(); 
        int startWord = 0;  
        String myWord = ""; 
        int numbLine = 1; 

        char[] barray = new char[1024]; 
        StringBuilder stringB = new StringBuilder(); 

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9]){0,}");

        try(BufferedReader  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("text.txt"))))
        {   
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int value;
            while((value = reader.read(barray, 0, barray.length)) != -1) {
                for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) {

                    stringB.append(barray[i]); 

                   if( Character.toString(barray[i]).equals("\n") ) {

                        Matcher m = p.matcher(stringB.toString());

                        if(m.matches()) {
                            finwWordLine = true;
                        }

                        if(finwWordLine) { 
                            System.out.println(numbLine + ": " +stringB.toString()); 
                        }

                        stringB.delete(0, stringB.length()); 
                        finwWordLine = false; 
                        numbLine++; 
                    }
} 

            }

           reader.close();



        }catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println("Error : "+e);
        }
    }
```

**UPD text.txt**

one line

two line

three line 
asd asdas das dasd asd
asdasdasd
five line

one

asdasd asd asd asd

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? An example with expected output would be better.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm trying to read a file character by character. At the same time I need to support regular expressions. I need to read the file exactly one character

Comment: @ThePerson No output line. without errors

Comment: Your example lacks of few `}` and example of input you want to parse with output you wan to achieve. Please [edit] your question and provide short but fully compilable and runnable example which will let us reproduce your problem.

Comment: @asdascascaedfa Can you post the content of the "text.txt" file please?

Comment: @Stephan i update question and add "text.txt"

Comment: @asdascascaedfa Which lines do you want to match? Which lines you DON'T to match?

Comment: @Stephan Line that matches the regular expression I want to display.

Comment: @asdascascaedfa In your text file, what are the **lines** you want to match? (the first, the third, tthe fitth one ... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex instead:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

Comment: @asdascascaedfa What do you want to match?

Comment: I want to bring those lines where the same regular expression. I my code i try I'm trying to do here `Matcher m = p.matcher(stringB.toString());` if there is a match then outputs a string

Comment: @asdascascaedfa In your post there is an example of the text.txt file. Among the 5 lines of this file, which ones are of interest ?

Comment: My regular expression `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9]){0,}");` in theory I should bring a string with one word, its line which contains the word **one** (4 line)

Comment: If i do like this `"([a-zA-Z0-9]){0,}([\\s]){0,}"`, that is to say it can be a space  `([\\s]){0,}` all good prints. I do not understand why.